# Copying a worksheet in Excel 2013 using VBA to the end of the workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am working in Excel 2013 and am having some trouble.  I have researched online all day and can't seem to find anything that solves my problem.

I have an Excel document that consists of 6 sheets:
Format
Summary
1.1 Detail
1.2 Detail
1.3 Detail
1.4 Detail

The 'detail' sheets are formatted all the same.  The 'Summary' sheet rolls up all the values from the 'details' sheets and has all kinds of charts and useful information in it.  The 'format' sheet is what I created to try to make this document more dynamic and useful for all different kinds of projects.  This document is being used for estimating projects, so different projects are going to have different amounts of 'details' sheets.

SO, my goal is to have a blank in the 'format' sheet that asks how many details are needed.  When the user types in 5, the code will add a sheet named '1.5 Detail' to the end of the workbook and have it formatted the same as the other 'details' sheets.  Is this possible using VBA? Also, is there a way to make the charts and formulas include the new tab when it is added without manually going and adding it to everything?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Adding the sheet (1.5 Detail) and the format shouldn't be an issue.  What is the formatting you need? (Bold header row, is a column set to, say, "Accounting" format?).

Comment: It is possible, but... what if user types in 15? Is it supposed to create 11 new sheets? What if user types in 3? Is it supposed to delete 1.4 Detail? Might be easier to have an Add button that just adds one sheet at a time, copied with the same formats as the other detail sheets. But it can be done either way.

Comment: Yes, it may go down to 3 and up to probably 8 at the most.  It is a project cost estimating tool, so as projects change the number of details change.My problem with just adding another sheet and copy and pasting the cells is that all of my (long,tedious) formulas on the 'Summary" sheet and all of the charts have to be manually updated so that the new tabs are included.  That is what I have been doing and it takes days.  This is a very big document with a lot of data. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using 3-D references on the summary sheet?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: 3-D references make summary formulas much easier to deal manage when adding new sheets:  https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-a-3-D-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-40ca91ff-9dcb-4ad1-99d2-787d0bc888b6

Comment: The problem with that is that each 'Detail' sheet has 4 tables: one for labor, travel, contracts, and equipment.  Not every sheet has the total in the same cell because some tables need more rows say if they have more equipment in that area.  For example, the 1.1 Detail labor total is in E17 and the 1.2 Detail labor total is in E20.

Comment: That's unfortunate, as 3-D references were specifically added to Excel for the purpose of rolling up detail sheets into summary sheets. But there remains the possibility to use them in your case if you can do the summary calculations from the summary sheet... This can be in addition to the summary calculation on each sheet...

Comment: So rather than summing one cell from each of the sheets, you would sum the appropriate table ranges from each of the sheets and do that by formula in the summary sheet, using 3D referencing.

Comment: I'm going to write an answer to respond further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you had three detail worksheets named: d_1, d_2, and d_3.

Each has an Excel Table named Labor with a column entitled "Cost". Each Labor table has a unique number of data rows.

On a summary sheet you could sum all of them like so:

```
=SUM(d_1:d_3!Labor[Cost])
```

The above will give you the labor cost grand total from all sheets. It is summing all of the rows from the tables and is not dependent on any summary information in the detail sheets.

So if you add a new detail sheet, d_4, then yes the example formula would need to be updated. HOWEVER, there is an old trick to get around this...

Create two additional sheets with the same tables, but with only one row of ZERO values in each table. Call the first one of these sheets "START". Call the second one of these sheets "END". Place START immediately before the first detail sheet, and place END immediately after the last detail sheet. NOW MAKE BOTH INVISIBLE.

Finally change the example formula to:

```
=SUM(START:END!Labor[Cost])
```

Now when new detail sheets are added, d_4, d_5, d_6, d_n, no change needs to happen to the formula on the summary sheet, yet all of the new data are included in the summary calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count` to count the number of sheets. Then `if` it is less, use `Worksheets.Add` and `ActiveSheet.Move After:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)` to add it on to the end.